# Excel VBA: How to find max/min of a range while ignoring error cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How can I use VBA in Excel to determine the max/min of a range that contains error cells such as `#N/A` or empty cells?  I know this is a fairly easy task to conquer with Excel array formulas using something like
 `=MIN(IF(A1:A10="#N/A"))`

but I would very much like to accomplish this using VBA.

I'm dealing with several thousand lines of data so the speediest solution would be preferred.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Evaluate` or the shortcut `[]` to return the VBA equivalent of a formula

So the Excel array formula
`=MIN(IF(NOT(ISNA(A1:A10)),A1:A10))`
can be used in code like

```
Sub Test()
MsgBox [MIN(IF(NOT(ISNA(A1:A10)),A1:A10))]
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `ISERROR` instead of `ISNA`, just to make sure it ignores all errors.

Comment: @DanielCook That may lead to an issue if a different error (say Div#0) is indicative of a data problem. So possibly yes, but it may be more robust just to use `ISNA`